# Check if each o365 group in a list is hidden from GAL

Tags: powershell, office365

I have a list of office 365 groups. I want to check if they are hidden from Global Address List. For some reason when I run foreach loop there is no output at all. Could you, please point out what I am doing wrong.

Here's how I connected to Exchange:

```
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
    Import-PSSession $Session
```

This is what I've tried to do:

```
#get list of o365 groups
$teams  = Get-UnifiedGroup |Where-Object {$_.WelcomeMessageEnabled -like "False"}|select -ExpandProperty Alias

#check $teams type just to be on the safe side
$teams.gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array

#check content of $teams variable

$teams
AllEMEA
AmericasApps
AmericasAR
AmericasConnectivity
AnalystTeam
APACExtendedServices
APACGatewayMigration
APACMarketGateways
APACProfessionalServices
APACSales
```

When I manually check groups one by one, it works just fine.

```
Get-UnifiedGroup -Filter {Alias -eq "AllEMEA"} | select DisplayName,hiddenfromaddresslistsenabled

DisplayName HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled
----------- -----------------------------
All EMEA                            False
```

But when i pipe $teams to foreach loop it hangs for a moment like it processes the array but then, there is no output at all.

```
>$teams | %{Get-UnifiedGroup -Filter {Alias -eq $_}} | select DisplayName,hiddenfromaddresslistsenabled
>

#I've tried this approach (which is as far as i know the same), but result is the same
>foreach ($team in $teams) {Get-UnifiedGroup -Filter {Alias -eq "$team"}} | select DisplayName,hiddenfromaddresslistsenabled
>
```

I want to see a list of groups and their *hiddenfromaddresslistsenabled* property. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Found a way to get what I want. Still not clear why I can't use "-filter" parameter.

I used "Identity" parameter instead of "Filter" and it worked: 

$teams | %{Get-UnifiedGroup -Identity "$_"} | select DisplayName,hiddenfromaddresslistsenabled

Answer (score 1):

Can you check the following code below?

```
$teams = Get-UnifiedGroup | Where {($_.HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled -eq $True) -and ($_.WelcomeMessageEnabled -like $false)} | ft Name, Alias, HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled, WelcomeMessageEnabled
$teams.gettype() <# if you need to check the type #>
$teams
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is  `-Filter` parameter does not accept pipeline input.

```
    Filter <string>
    Required?                    true
    Position?                    Named
    Accept pipeline input?       false
    Parameter set name           Filter
    Aliases                      None
    Dynamic?                     true
```

I see the same behavior with `Get-aduser -Filter`,for example, so the workaround here is to not use `-Filter` but use `-Identity` parameter which accepts pipeline input.
The @Nevenka's answer works as well, but I wanted to post the root cause for this problem, if anyone will encounter the same problem.